# I get following error : start npm in react native spawn cmd ENOENT

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get the following error:

> Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
>   Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
>   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
>   at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)npm ERR! code LIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Answer (score 0):

Do you have watchman installed?

If not then install  it, it is required

https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html

maybe this thread can lead to your solution

https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/533#issuecomment-358333117